# How to implement let as a lambda function in Scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, let

As an exercise I am trying to define let as a lambda function something like this:

```
(define let_as_lambda 
  (lambda (var) 
     (lambda (value body) 
       (var body) val)))
```

And I am hoping to call it like this:

```
((let_as_lambda a) (3 (+ a 2)))
```

However there is no way to pass an unbound variable (in this case "a") as an argument to a function. (I know it looks a little strange but I need let_as_lambda(var) to return a function.)

Can anyone show me how to do this? Any advice is appreciated.

In fact, just using this lambda-equivalent expression:

```
(let ((p1 v1) (p2 v2)...) body) = ((lambda (p1 p2...) body) v1 v2...)
```

I can't even get this to work:

```
(define let_as_lambda 
    (lambda (var val body) 
      ((var body) val)))
```

Called by: `(let_as_lambda a 3 (+ a 2))`

Without getting the same complaint:

reference to an identifier before its definition: a

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand you. You have the definition of let as a function already. Variables are bound by parameters. If you change the order in `((let_as_lambda a) (3 (+ a 2)))` to something like `((let_as_lambda (a) (+ a 2)) 3)` then `let_as_lambda` is the same as `lambda`. ... But if you want to build an interpreter then you need the concept of an environment as a mapping from names (strings) to values. But this needs a little bit of extra work.

Comment: Hi.  I'll simplify my exercise a little.  I already know that:

(let ((p1 v1) (p2 v2)...) body) = ((lambda (p1 p2...) body) v1 v2...)

and I would like to just write this as a new rule such as:

(define let_as_lambda
   (lambda ...

The problem occurs with any function call like:

(let_as_lambda a 3 (+ a 2))

since a is being referenced before it is being defined -- the definition occuring in the body of let_as_lambda.

Is there any way to pass "a" as an unbound variable or is there some other way to define let_as_lambda?

Comment: For simplicity: No, you can not pass an unbound variable as a paramameter to functions. There are some tricks but probably that is not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let` is a syntatic extension defined in terms of `lambda`. I don't think you can define it as a function. Take a look at the example from [The Scheme Programming Language](http://www.scheme.com/tspl3/further.html#./further%3ah1)