# Converting Let Form procedure into Unnamed (anonymous) procedure

Tags: scheme, racket

I am having problems understanding how to convert Let Form procedure into Unnamed (anonymous) procedures. There is not much material on the subject online or examples. Can anyone help?

```
(let ((x 30))
  (let ((x (+ 5 25)) (y (* 5 x)))
    (* x y 24)))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement let as a lambda function in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059841/how-to-implement-let-as-a-lambda-function-in-scheme)

Answer (score 1):

```
((lambda (x)
   ((lambda (x y)
      (* x y 24))
    (+ 5 25) (* 5 x)))
 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

"There is not much material on the subject online or examples."

Did you try looking up the definition of `let` in any Scheme standard?

```
(define-syntax let
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((let ((name val) ...) body1 body2 ...)
     ((lambda (name ...) body1 body2 ...)
      val ...))
    ;; ignore 'named-let'
    ))
```

The above isn't the solution to your homework problem but understanding the above will allow you to solve your homework problem.

Comment: That requires the OP to know how to read `syntax-rules` macros, which is not a skill they'd have if they're just doing 101-level coursework. :-P